# Apache points to wrong vhost conf file

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu

I have a fresh VPS on Ubuntu 18. Have installed only PHP and Apache. Created only a one vhost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName vp123.ovh.net
  DocumentRoot /var/www/app
</VirtualHost>
```

After apache realod, the domain is pointing to default folder **/var/www/html** instead of my **/var/www/app**

000-default.conf is default:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

apache2ctl -S outputs:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server vp123.ovh.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost vp123.ovh.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost vp123.ovh.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/vp123.ovh.net.conf:1)

ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

When pointing a new domain to this server - works perfect. But this "default domain" is always pointing to default folder. Disabling 000-default.conf helps but I don't want do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The virtual host defined at `000-default.conf` doesn't have a `ServerName` directive so it [inherits the value from its parent container](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost) (in this case the main server settings) and I presume such directive also has `vp123.ovh.net` as value. Thus Apache considers the first virtual host matches.

> A `ServerName` should be specified inside each `<VirtualHost>` block. If it is absent, the `ServerName` from the "main" server configuration will be inherited.

Since you want to use that name elsewhere a possible solution is to set a explicit value that doesn't interfere, e.g.:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache selects the virtual host as described in the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/details.html).

Considering the vhost selection process your options are:

1. Disable the default vHost, you don't need it.
2. Really. Why would you want to keep it?
3. Change the default vHost declaration to `<VirtualHost *>`. Therefore making the other vHost the default for requests targeted at port 80.
4. Add your servers ip address to your vhost declaration. (`<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>`) It will then take precedence over the default vhost `*:80` for requests targeted at that IP-address. Note that requests to other to other IPs of your server will still be served by the `*:80`-vHost.
5. Set `DocumentRoot /var/www/app` inside your default vHost. This will require you to make configuration changes in multiple vHost each time and thus increases the chance of making mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,

#1,2 - I want to keep it in case I have many domains pointing to my server and show a default "maintance in progress..." page when vhost for this domain is not created yet.

#3 - default vhost is ok for me.

#4 - this is working. But in the doc. there is: if the IP and port are the same "Apache will further compare the ServerName" - so should choose vps123.ovh.net.conf because it has declarated ServerName (and 000-default doesn't). So why it is choosing 000-default?

#5 - I want use /www/app folder only for this one vhost, not for each.